# why can't incorrect router path be handled by errorRouter(Node.js)?

Tags: node.js

```
<!-- testRouter -->
router.get('/ex' handler); //1
router.get('ex', handler); //2

<!-- errorRouter -->
router.get((req, res, next) {
    err = new Error();
    next(err);
}
router.get((err, req,res,next) {
    res.send('Error');
}
<!-- main -->
app = express();
app.use('/', testRouter);
app.use(errorRouter);
```

When I use '1', it works well, but '2' waits infinitely. But..
Shouldn't it go to the errorRouter because there is no address?
Why can't it be handled by errorRouter?

Comment: It should catch it, can you post full code of your errorRouter

Comment: @Navitas28 I miss res.render() in errorRouter.. Now It works well!

Comment: I solve it! I set auto_flush=True, then it work well.